# Десятичный хэш

Tags: алгоритм, php, хеширование

Числовые ключи в MySQL работают много быстрее, чем строковые. 
Нужно изготовить десятичные числа из любого хэша.

На стэке нашел решение примерно такое:

```
hexdec(substr(md5($element_id),-15,15)));
```

Есть ли более изящные методы получения десятичного хэша?

P.S. более изящных методов ведения БД пока что предлагать **не нужно**.
Первая строка дана только для ориентировки, например, по длине, либо чтобы не возникло возражения, что шестнадцатиричное число - тоже число.

Comment: Вот так еще можно попробовать:  

    bindec(md5($string, true));

Comment: Не катит. Такой длины число оно не понимает, а если урезать, то см мой вариант. =)
MD4 тоже не спасет. 
Да и база поймет, если результат будет 19 значным числом(или 20 unsigned).

Comment: Как вариант, это обрезать сырую строку мд5 до 8 символов, и биндек к ней. По сути тоже самое, как и в вопросе, но быстрее гораздо должно быть.

Comment: А чем можно обрезать сырую строку? О_о

Comment: Неясно выразился.  

   bindec(substr(md5($string, true), -8, 8)

Comment: Да, как-то с ходу не подумал, что будут ffff и 6666 совпадать, хотя вообще в 32-байтном шифре это будет не сильно заметно и пользоваться будет можно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Лично мне кажется, что эта задача неразрешима, поскольку все варианты с выделением фрагмента уникального хэша автоматически теряют свойство уникальности, и не могут использоваться в качестве ключа.

> Что-то похожее на ваш вариант, кстати говоря, делается [**здесь**](http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2010/03/generating-unique-integer-ids-from-strings-in-mysql/) (на основании хэша `sha1`).

- То есть, вы, конечно, можете воспользоваться своим вариантом  *(да и любым другим вариантом с конвертированием некоторой значимой части уникального хэша)*, однако рискуете нарваться на неприятности в случае большого количества записей в базе данных или в случае, если звезды будут неблагосклонны :)

> Тем более, я думаю, что если такое преобразование было бы возможным, то это **давным давно уже было бы реализовано** на стороне популярных баз данных, которые допускают строковые ключи.

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понимаю, почему это неразрешимая коллизия. Давайте посмотрим спокойно:

1. Есть набор байтов представляющих из себя некий хэш
2. Набор байтов однозначно и всегда (взаимно обратимо) транслируется в целое значение - вопрос только в длине набора байтов.

Пример: есть допустим хэш длиной 8 байт - это всегда и взаимно обратимо можно переложить на `long` (Java).

Весь вопрос только упирается в длину целого. В Java этой проблемы не существует - ибо всегда можно: `new BigInteger(byte[] val)` и получить целое произвольной длины.

Comment: В Java BigInteger(byte[] val)// вот за это однозначно спасибо. =)
ЧТо же касается этого метода для БД, то для мускуля, например, такой финт уже не прокатит, увы.

Answer (score 0):

А не проще вычислять хэш самому? https://code.google.com/p/boyanov/wiki/FNVHash

Comment: @VadimTukaev, вряд ли этот метод подойдет. 

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что все должно решаться на уровне SQL.

Хотя, в вопросе есть метка ПХП...

Comment: Я не очень знаю специфику SQL. Что будет, если в запрос, ожидающий число, направить строку из букв и цифр? Если он отфильтрует буквы, а оставшиеся цифры превратит в число, то этого может хватить. Очевидно, что при этом мы можем получить число с количество цифр от 0 до 32, но в среднем это будет 20-значное число. Более чем достаточно, ИМХО.