# Перевести строковый индетификатор в числовой. PHP

Tags: php

Есть база данных и в качестве первичного ключа используется строка как его возможно преобразовать в уникальное число (желательно не слишком длинное)?

Comment: хеширование? желательно самопальное а не md5.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132790/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88 Может поможет.

Comment: ну да. мд5 выдает длинный набор символов

Comment: Other спасибо за ссылку